# Is there a reason my batch file won't run my python script? No errors given

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, anaconda

I'm trying to create a batch file that can execute my python script to update data. Since python needs to be run in my anaconda env, I was able to have the batch file open the anaconda prompt, however it does not run the python script. My code is below.

```
@echo
call %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64' " 
python movehist.py
@pause
```

Comment: Commands in a batch file run sequentially. The first line creates a separate execution environment.  The second line does _not_ run within that environment; it runs when the first command is _finished_.

Comment: I should also mention the python script itself runs manually and outputs the desired result.

Comment: @JohnGordon how can I get it to run in the environment that is established prior?

Comment: `Call` is for running a batch file from another batch file, not for running an exe file from a batch file, so remove the `call` from line two.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to succesfully run the batch file!!